# Alignment HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my text to align. I have a `<p>` and my text goes all the way from the left of the webbrowser/screen till the right. But I want it to be away from the left and right ends of the screen. I know of the alignment code "center, right, left, etc.". I need it to be left aligned, but not right next to the screen, like if the whole `<p>` was indented on both sides.

Comment: You can just add some padding to it, i.e. `padding:0 30px;` change `30px` to whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to either put it within a containing div, or apply padding to the `<p>` tag. It would look like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel sem ultrices, pellentesque risus sit amet, scelerisque sem. Mauris ut mauris a libero dictum viverra. Ut eros metus, tristique et porta quis, tincidunt quis lacus. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sit amet nisi nec urna tincidunt malesuada. Nulla blandit feugiat dolor, a luctus dolor interdum ut. Quisque laoreet leo tristique, vestibulum enim eget, imperdiet sem.</p>
</div>
```

OR

```html
<p style="padding:0 50px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel sem ultrices, pellentesque risus sit amet, scelerisque sem. Mauris ut mauris a libero dictum viverra. Ut eros metus, tristique et porta quis, tincidunt quis lacus. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sit amet nisi nec urna tincidunt malesuada. Nulla blandit feugiat dolor, a luctus dolor interdum ut. Quisque laoreet leo tristique, vestibulum enim eget, imperdiet sem.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add some padding, margin-left/margin-right, or another solution like that.

Try adding;

```
text-align: left;
margin-left: 5%;
```

to your CSS.

You can change the `margin-left` value to be an amount of pixels (e.g. `50px;`) or leave it as percentage of it's parent element.

You said you wanted the text left aligned but not have it touch the left side of the page. Here is a JSFiddle of that:

https://jsfiddle.net/zfvhgr0x/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply by keeping the width attribute as is and just including the following into your CSS:

```
padding: 0 5px;
```

This will add a space of 5 pixels to the left of your text, and the right of your text. This means that if your text would reach the end of the screen, it would stop 5 pixels before the end.

You can set each indent individually, as explained below:

```
padding: 5px(top) 7px(right) 2px(bottom) 10px(left)
```

When putting this in code, you do not want the brackets. These are just there for demonstration purposes to explain what each of the numbers will target.

Hope that helps!